# Mysql: How to add a unique column to an existing table in 1 line?

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 lines

```
ALTER TABLE User ADD mwaProfileId INT(10) null;
ALTER TABLE User ADD UNIQUE (mwaProfileId);
```

But how to combine them into 1 line pls ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE User ADD mwaProfileId INT(10) NULL, ADD UNIQUE (mwaProfileId) ;`

Comment: that's still 2 line

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` is *one* SQL statement on exactly *one* line (since there are no line break / newline / carriage return characters in the SQL text) . One big advantage of this form of the syntax is that it's a single statement (obtains the table lock, applies both of the changes as a single unit of work, which either succeeds completely or fails and rolllsback, and then releases the lock. This form of the statement allows us to provide a name for the index ... but then again, providing help to someone under the impression there's no disadvantages to mixed case tablenames, so there's that

Answer (score 1):

You could use syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE User ADD mwaProfileId INT(10) null UNIQUE;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c757368cbb82d02c8b9fcffa37ac385a)**